# django-crispy form - hide field label

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have a cripsy django form.

What is the best way to hide the field label in the template when I use `{% cripsy form %}`?

I do not want the user to see `MY_FIELD_1 and MY_FIELD_2`.

```
class mYForm(forms.ModelForm):
    MY_FIELD_1 = forms.BooleanField()

    MY_FIELD_2 = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        ...
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('MY_FIELD_1',),
            Field('MY_FIELD_2',),
        )
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove *all* labels from your form when using the crispy forms `FormHelper` then you can use:

```
self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

If you want to remove labels from certain fields then you can do

```
self.fields['some_field'].label = False
```

Where `some_field` is the name of the field whose label you want to remove.

Comment: This looks logical and simple, but it doesn't work for me for some reason. Labels still show up.

Comment: I can see the `form_show_labels` property in the `LayoutHelper` object, but still doesn't work. Settings the individual fields worked though. :P

Comment: @CsabaToth Sod you set self.helper = FormHelper(self)?

Comment: @Pythonista I say this `self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)`